# if/else statements in for loop not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that asks for user input and the for loop should check if the input of both user id and pin matches any of the ten pre-made account's user id and pin, like an authorization system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct account{
    int uid;
    int pin;
    int user_bal;
};


int main()
{
    int scan_uid, scan_pin;
    int att = 3;
    bool loop = true;

    struct account user[10];

    user[0].uid = 1234;
    user[0].pin = 123456;

    user[1].uid = 4181;
    user[1].pin = 308592;

    user[2].uid =1111;
    user[2].pin =111111;

    user[3].uid =2222;
    user[3].pin =222222;

    user[4].uid =4444;
    user[4].pin =444444;

    user[5].uid =5555;
    user[5].pin =555555;

    user[6].uid =6666;
    user[6].pin =666666;

    user[7].uid =7777;
    user[7].pin =777777;

    user[8].uid =8888;
    user[8].pin =888888;

    user[9].uid =9999;
    user[9].pin =999999;

    for (int i; i <= 9; i++){
        user[i].user_bal = 1000;
    }

    do{
        printf("\nEnter your user ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &scan_uid);
        printf("Enter your pin: ");
        scanf("%d", &scan_pin);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------\n");
        att--;
        for (int i; i <= 9; ++i){
            //printf("\n%d", i);
            //printf("\n%d", user[i].uid);
            //printf("\n%d", user[i].pin);
            //printf("\n%d", scan_uid);
            //printf("\n%d", scan_pin);
            if (user[i].uid == scan_uid && user[i].pin == scan_pin){
                loop = false;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nThe username or password is incorrect!");
                printf("\nYou have %d attempt(s) left.", att);
                if (att > 0)
                {
                    printf("\nPlease try again.\n");
                }
                else if (att == 0)
                {
                    printf("\nUnauthorized Access.");
                    printf("\nReport for stolen credit card uploaded.");
                }
            }
        }
    }while (att > 0 || loop == false);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the relatively same code in python and it works perfectly there. I also checked if the "i" is correct and incremented and if it scanned the user input correctly. all ok. But i've hit a brick wall trying to solve why it just skips the 'if/else' and just scans input again.

I also tried an 'else if ' that does the opposite(!=) of the initial 'if' statement, with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to initialize i in the for loop.  (e.g. for (int i=0; i <= 9; ++i))

Comment: Please, never say "not working", especially in the title. Say the *exact* error you're getting. Explain what you're trying to do and where it went wrong.

Comment: Tip: Don't compare `bool` values, just `if (x)` or `if (!x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out that you need to initialize `int i` with `int i = 0` in your `for` loop.

However, I would additionally like to point out several other mistakes here. First, your loop condition appears to be incorrect:

```
while (att > 0 || loop == false)
```

You want to continue the loop in the case where they haven't entered the correct value yet and where they still have more attempts left. However, as written, this will continue to loop even if the user enters the correct password. I think that this should actually be

```
while (att > 0 && loop == true)
```

Also, most languages don't require you to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`, so the following is stylistically better:

```
while (att > 0 && loop)
```

Also, as written, it prompts the user to try again; however, it doesn't prompt the user for input again after the first time, so it's impossible for the user to try again. You need to prompt the user for input again inside the loop if their input was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. As Dan said, initialize `i` to 0. This will fix the segfault.
2. When you do `loop = false;` you need `break;` immediately afterwards.
3. And, your do/while condition is wrong. Change `while (att > 0 || loop == false);` into `while ((att > 0) && loop);`
4. The placement of the "incorrect passwords" related `printf` is incorrect. It should come *after* the `for`.
5. Otherwise, the same error message will be repeated 9 times for a single incorrect answer.
6. And, we want to exit the do/while loop [immediately after the `for` loop] if we see `loop` become false.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct account {
    int uid;
    int pin;
    int user_bal;
};

int
main(void)
{
    int scan_uid,
     scan_pin;
    int att = 3;
    bool loop = true;

    struct account user[10];

    user[0].uid = 1234;
    user[0].pin = 123456;

    user[1].uid = 4181;
    user[1].pin = 308592;

    user[2].uid = 1111;
    user[2].pin = 111111;

    user[3].uid = 2222;
    user[3].pin = 222222;

    user[4].uid = 4444;
    user[4].pin = 444444;

    user[5].uid = 5555;
    user[5].pin = 555555;

    user[6].uid = 6666;
    user[6].pin = 666666;

    user[7].uid = 7777;
    user[7].pin = 777777;

    user[8].uid = 8888;
    user[8].pin = 888888;

    user[9].uid = 9999;
    user[9].pin = 999999;

    for (int i; i <= 9; i++) {
        user[i].user_bal = 1000;
    }

    do {
        printf("\nEnter your user ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &scan_uid);
        printf("Enter your pin: ");
        scanf("%d", &scan_pin);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------\n");
        att--;
// NOTE/BUG: i is uninitialized
#if 0
        for (int i; i <= 9; ++i) {
#else
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
#endif
            // printf("\n%d", i);
            // printf("\n%d", user[i].uid);
            // printf("\n%d", user[i].pin);
            // printf("\n%d", scan_uid);
            // printf("\n%d", scan_pin);
            if (user[i].uid == scan_uid && user[i].pin == scan_pin) {
                loop = false;
// NOTE/FIX: no need to continue loop if we get a match
#if 1
                break;
#endif
            }
        }

#if 1
        // stop if everything matched
        if (! loop)
            break;
#endif

        printf("\nThe username or password is incorrect!");
        printf("\nYou have %d attempt(s) left.", att);
        if (att > 0) {
            printf("\nPlease try again.\n");
        }
        else if (att == 0) {
            printf("\nUnauthorized Access.");
            printf("\nReport for stolen credit card uploaded.");
        }
    } while (att > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should initialize i to 0
2. To browse all array contents, you should increment i after the instruction NOT before (i++) instead of (++i)
3. Condition while loop is WRONG

Look at this version of your code, It works properly:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct account{
    int uid;
    int pin;
    int user_bal;
};


int main()
{
    int scan_uid, scan_pin;
    int att = 3;
    bool loop = true;

    struct account user[10] = {0};
    user[0].uid = 1234;
    user[0].pin = 123456;

    user[1].uid = 4181;
    user[1].pin = 308592;

    user[2].uid =1111;
    user[2].pin =111111;

    user[3].uid =2222;
    user[3].pin =222222;

    user[4].uid =4444;
    user[4].pin =444444;

   user[5].uid =5555;
   user[5].pin =555555;

   user[6].uid =6666;
   user[6].pin =666666;

   user[7].uid =7777;
   user[7].pin =777777;

   user[8].uid =8888;
   user[8].pin =888888;

   user[9].uid =9999;
   user[9].pin =999999;

   for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
       user[i].user_bal = 1000;
   }

   do{
       printf("\n--------------------------------------------\n");
       printf("\nEnter your user ID: ");
       scanf("%d", &scan_uid);
       printf("Enter your pin: ");
       scanf("%d", &scan_pin);
       printf("\n--------------------------------------------\n");
       att--;
       for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
           //printf("\n%d", i);
           //printf("\n%d", user[i].uid);
           //printf("\n%d", user[i].pin);
           //printf("\n%d", scan_uid);
           //printf("\n%d", scan_pin);
           if (user[i].uid == scan_uid && user[i].pin == scan_pin)
           {
               loop = false;
               break;
           }
    }
    if (loop && att)
    {
        printf("\nThe username or password is incorrect!");
        printf("\nYou have %d attempt(s) left.", att);
    }
    else if (! att && loop)
    {
        printf("\nUnauthorized Access.");
        printf("\nReport for stolen credit card uploaded.\n");
    }
    else if (!loop)
    {
        printf("\nMatches !\n");
    }
} while ((att > 0) && (loop == true));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `} while ((att > 0) & (loop == true));`   the `&` is the wrong operator  Should be" `&&`

Comment: Yes, You have right. Its a typo ...

Comment: Hi. Point 2 (about `++i` vs `i++`) is irrelevant. The value of the expression isn't used.